# How to use Letsencrypt to domain that has no root folder with Cloudflare?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, domain, lets-encrypt, cloudflare

I am trying to use Letsencrypt (HTTPS) on my website with Cloudflare (HTTP) but I confuse with this.

1. the domain doesn't have a root folder
2. accessing domain will be redirected to one of subdomains

   - domain.com -> sub1.domain.com
3. I have many subdomains

   - domain.com redirect to sub1.domain.com
   - sub1.domain.com
   - sub2.domain.com
   - etc..

I am using ubuntu server 16.04 with apache.

My question, How to use Letsencrypt to my website with configuration above (domain.com has no root folder ) with Cloudflare?

Thank you

Comment: https://bjornjohansen.no/wildcard-certificate-letsencrypt-cloudflare

Comment: Hi Marcel,

As I know the if use letsencrypt it will need to access the .well-known folder. If I use the method above, how about the .well-known folder?

sorry for many questions.

Comment: No, with lets encrypt there are many types of verification of domain ownership. Check their manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup in apache a vhost for e.g. letsencrypt and Proxy the ".well-known"-folder to this domain.

**Step 1: Setup Lets encrypt vhost**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      lets-encrypt-proxy.domain.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/letsencrypt
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 2: Configure ProxyPass**

You can setup this ProxyPass e.g. in /etc/httpd/conf.d/letsencrypt.conf or confire direcly in the specified vhost. If you're setup a file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/letsencrypt.conf copy the following line into this file:

```
ProxyPass /.well-known/acme-challenge/ http://letsencrypt.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

Make sure, that in your existing vhost the file correct redirected to the proxypass e.g. or you post the ProxyPass directly to the vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?.well-known/acme-challenge/ - [L]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Hi Giuliano Schindler, I just want to make sure. all I need is only insert the text above to vhost domain, right?